# How can I add a second form to my Django Project?

Tags: python, django

I am new about Django , Python and in general web programming. I have a maybe a stupid problem but I am here trying to fix it from a week ago.

I have a Django project about food , I want two forms, first one is register a user(membresia or usuario)  this works fine. and the other one is register a restaurant.

My Django version is 1.10

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.


class Membresia(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cedula = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    celular = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creado_en = models.DateTimeField(
                default=timezone.now)

class Restaurante(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nombre_responsable = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    celular = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    creado_en = models.DateTimeField(
                default=timezone.now)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Membresia, Restaurante





class membresiaform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Membresia
        fields = ('nombre', 'cedula','celular','email','ciudad','direccion')
        widgets = {
            'nombre':  forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Tu nombre'}),
            'cedula':  forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Tu número cédula'}),
            'celular': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Tu número celular'}),
            'email':   forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Tu correo electrónico'}),
            'ciudad':  forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Ciudad donde vives'}),
            'direccion': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Tu dirección'}),

        }

class restauranteform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurante
        fields = ('nombre','nombre_responsable','direccion','celular','ciudad','email')
        widgets = {
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Nombre del restaurante'}),
            'nombre_responsable': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Nombre del representante '}),
            'direccion': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Dirección del restaurante'}),
            'celular' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'El celular de contácto'}),
            'ciudad': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Ciudad de ubicación restaurante'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','placeholder': 'Correo eléctronico'}),

        }
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response
from .forms import membresiaform, restauranteform
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.utils import timezone





# Create your views here.


def registrar_usuario_web(request):
    if "submit_us" in  request.POST:

        form = membresiaform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.creado_en = timezone.now()
            form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = membresiaform()

    return render(request,'web/registrarusuario.html', {'form': form})

def registrar_restaurante_Web(request):
    if "submit_res" in  request.POST:
        form = restauranteform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.creado_en = timezone.now()
            form.save

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = restauranteform()

    return render(request,'web/registrarrestaurante.html',{'form':form})
```

registrarrestaurante.html

```
{% block content %}
        <form action="/restaurante/registrar/" method="POST">
            <div class="post">
              <h1>Registrar restaurante</h1>
              {% csrf_token %}
                  {{ form.as_p }}
          {% endblock %}


          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" name="submit_res" class="btn btn-submit" value="Enviar">
          </div>
      </form>
```

I can't save data in my Restaurante database. I didnt see errors, and the form is valid. If I save data from Shell no problems. I searched questions here, but looks like everybody has the problem about to have two forms at same view, but I think this is not my problem, I someone can help me, I will be so grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real reason that you can't save data into your table is because of this:

```
form.save
```

it should be

```
form.save()
```

Having solved that there are several other things to consider. For example, Shouldn't your members be allowed to login? If yes, you are reinventing the wheel here. YOu could use django.contrib.auth.models.User as your user model and make use of one of the many tried and tested django authentication systems such as django-registration to get this task done with little or no effort.

Comment: I am ashamed , its so stupid the error, thanks a lot, I feel sad and happy at the same time. Well actually I am only practicing with this example, I was not thinkin do login, but thanks anyway because now I know how to do it.

Comment: glad to have helped. Everyone makes mistakes like this at the start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a rails developer, but I'm sure you can do this in Django as well.

I would add ID's to each submit button and forms then submit them using JS.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_res" class="btn btn-submit" value="Enviar" id='submit_res'>
```

then

```
$('#submit_res').click(function () {
   $('#restauranteform').submit();  
});

$('#id_of_other_button').click(function () {
   $('#id_of_other_form').submit();  
});
```

Comment: It was so stupid my error, thanks anyway, I can't vote you because my reputation.